# Locating an angular surface using GD&T

Tags: technical-drawing, drawings, tolerance

[image: Sample drawing]

I'm having doubts about how to dimension an angular surface using proper GD&T techniques. I want to achieve the 6 mm feature of size (FOS) at an angle of 89 deg. to Datum B to within an angularity tolerance of 0.2 mm and also to be perpendicular to Datum A to within 0.02 mm.
I also want to locate the 6 mm slot. Not sure if locating the point is the correct method. Can it be done using position tolerance?

Comment: For starters, angles to datum B should be specified against datum B rather than some other surface 7+.04/-0 off. It will improve clarity. Have you considered why you care about the constraints you want? What needs to mate/fit?

Comment: Yaa, maybe i should have drawn a centerline for 7 mm slot and shown the angle from there. Its a gripper finger. One surface shouldn't be too off from the other. Thats why it needs to be controlled. But other than that, whether what i have done is correct? @Abel